# Выбор области на карте MapKit Android

Tags: java, android, yandexmapkit, mapkit

Подскажите как реализовать обводку на карте mapkit по примеру циана? Юзер обводит нужную ему область с метками(может нарисовать на карте любую область), и может получить их в виде списка.

[image: Пример реализации в приложении ЦИАН]

Comment: Вот тут с 13 минуты есть что-то про это. Хоть видео и не новое, может будет полезно. https://youtu.be/BmOrIOVUgdE?t=780